# Plugin is attempting to start a session with WordPress. WP Session Manager will not work! DomPdf

Tags: session

I get the error message "Another plugin is attempting to start a session with WordPress. WP Session Manager will not work!  how to find error"

I am trying to correct the code of somebody. He uses dompf. There is stuff like $_Session in the code. What do I need to do with the code so there is no error anymore?

Comment: Contact the plugin support about this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.